# Find all numbers $c$ that satisfy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Verify that the function satisfies the hypotheses of the Mean Value Theorem on the given interval. Then find all numbers $c$ that satisfy the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem.

My function is a simple one: $x^{1/3}$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Where I'm screwing up (I believe) is setting the derivative $1/3(x^{-2/3})$ equal to $1$.
Sorry if that too many parentheses or too silly of a question. It's my first on here.
I know (via the back of the book) that the answer should be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}$

Thanks.

Comment: The derivative is $\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$, which is different from what you have written.

Comment: I should be $(1/3)x^{-2/3}$ or $1/(3x^{2/3})$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry guys, that's actually what I meant to put, I put a parenthesis too soon. I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{1}{3}x^{-2/3} = 1 \\ \implies \dfrac{1}{3}=x^{2/3} \\ \implies \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{3}=x^2 \\ \implies \sqrt{x^2}= \pm \sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{3}}$$ And for what it's worth, $$\sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{3}} = \sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)} \\ = \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ =  \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} \\ = \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\frac{1}{3} \cdot \sqrt{3} \\ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

Comment: Could you explain the logic between steps 1 and 2?

Comment: Multiply the equation by $x^{2/3}.$  Then $x^{2/3} \cdot x^{-2/3}= x^{2/3+(-2/3)}=x^0 = 1$

Comment: Ahh, beautiful.

Comment: Just a little algebra. You definitely had the calculus down for this problem!

Comment: I do have another problem here. I know that somehow the answer should be sqrt(3)/9. How is this?

Comment: Not all of these solutions are in the specified interval, however.

Comment: @DrakkorNoir edited my answer to show you. Just a little more algebra ;)

Comment: Right, I ignored the negative solutions to the problem. Thanks for that explanation, maybe I just need to get a good night's sleep or something lol.

Comment: Also since you are newer on here, I recommend giving this a quick read http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer